# How to pass Headers and x-www-form-urlencoded body in Autocannon

Tags: performance, http, performance-testing, wrk

I'm trying to pass Headers and x-www-form-urlencoded body in [Autocannon](https://github.com/mcollina/autocannon) POST request, but my response is always:

`0 2xx responses, 5 non 2xx responses`

Example from command line:

```
autocannon -c 1 -a 5 -H Authorization="Bearer xxxx",Content-Type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -b "Key"="Value" http://host.com:8080/path
```

Comment: I think you should remove the comma-separated. the headers should be key=value - for example:
-H Auth="Barear blabla" Another-Header="blabla"

Answer (score 3):

Use -H flag for each header like this :
autocannon -c 1 -a 5 -H "Authorization":"Bearer xxxx" -H "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -b '{"Key"="Value"}'
http://host.com:8080/path

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following data and you want to make a POST request using `x-www-form-urlencoded`:

**URL**
https://api.something.com

**Headers**
Authorization: Bearer some-extra-long-uuid=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Body**
field_1: value_1
field_2: value_2

For the above data, the `autocannon` CLI command would look something like below:

```
autocannon -m POST -H "Authorization":"Bearer some-extra-long-uuid=" -H "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -b "field_1=value_1&field_2=value_2" https://api.something.com
```